# MapReduce Java Program Error: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: mapreduce

I have run a MapReduce java program and run in Hadoop. I have not set some configuration right and I don't get my error. I tried with various workarounds but I get similar errors repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

You must make your mapper and reducer `public`:

```
public static class AnnualTaxCalculaterMapper
public static class AnnualTaxCalculaterReducer
```

The Hadoop API cannot access `package-private` class.

Comment: @user2391084 static AND public. Without the static keyword these classes are not instantiable without the outer classes instance.

Comment: @user2391084 No. The reason is that the API cannot find a constructor for AnnualTaxCalculaterMapper. Making the class ``public static`` should solve your problem.